# How to finalize/destroy class variable

Tags: vb.net, ole

I have a program that uses some sort of Ole connection to establish connection with a Cam/cad software Powershape. It uses a class variable to make connection with powershape and its properties contain info about the models open.

The problem is that this connection only ends when the class variable finalizes or goes out of scope.

```
Dim powershapeRoot As New PSAutomation(Delcam.ProductInterface.InstanceReuse.UseExistingInstance)
```

This works fine inside Subs since it goes out of scope, but this program requires you to do this several times when you need data from powershape and it can take some time to each time make the connection again. So you could make it Global variable so you only need the connection once.

```
Dim powershapeRoot As New PSAutomation(Delcam.ProductInterface.InstanceReuse.UseExistingInstance)
Powershapeglobal = powershapeRoot
```

But now the variable only goes out of scope once the program is closed. I tried to use:

```
Powershapeglobal.dispose
Powershapeglobal = nothing
```

These did not help and the connection still seems to be existing because the variable still exists? How do you destroy the variable for good?

Comment: In VBA you would use "Set" keyword to set an object variabile to "Nothing"

Comment: Besides correctly releasing the COM object so that the Pointer no longer exists, you should also free up the object for GC. Andrew Whitechapel covers this fairly well in his book, the relevant extract in the section about releasing COM objects: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa679807(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: It sounds like a bug in the PSAutomation class you rely on. A properly designed and implemented class would use the IDisposable pattern for this.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET, unmanaged resources are not destroyed when a .NET variable goes out of scope. They are destroyed when the Garbage Collector removes them from memory, which is whenever the Garbage Collector feels that that is necessary. This is called "non-deterministic finalization" because you, the developer do not determine the exact moment that objects are finalized.

To ensure that external resources are cleaned up when you are done with them, call the Dispose() method of the object in question:

```
  Dim powershapeRoot As New PSAutomation(Delcam.ProductInterface.InstanceReuse.UseExistingInstance)
```

And, when you want to release the connection:

```
  powershapeRoot.Dispose();
```

Or, to get the Dispose to happen automatically, use the .NET "Using" statement:

```
 Using powershapeRoot As New PSAutomation(Delcam.ProductInterface.InstanceReuse.UseExistingInstance)



 End Using ' Dispose is called automatically here
```

Now, with COM objects there is another step to the process, you must explicitly call the ReleaseComObject() method, like this:

```
 System.Marshall.ReleaseComObject(powershapeRoot);
```

And then call Dispose() AFTER that. However, this is only needed when you have made an explicit reference to a COM assembly. With OleDB connections, calling Dispose is enough.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject(v=vs.110).aspx